# Why are datatable rows still filtered after clearing RowFilter?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

I have a `DataTable` with 1 row. I get the related `DataView` and set its `RowFilter` to `""` or `NULL`.

When I get the `Count` property, the value for the `DataView` is 0.

Why setting `RowFilter` to `""`, is still filtering the rows? I would expect the `Count` to have value of 1.

Comment: Can you post the block of code where the issue is happening?

Comment: Thanks @NoSaidTheCompiler, but I have since tested similar code elsewhere and there was no problem. So I shall have to look at my problem more deeply!